# Check-in policy tab is missing in Source Control settings in VS2019 Professional

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2019

I am not able to see Check-in policy tab in Source Control settings in VS2019 Professional.

It is visible in 2015. Am i missing any plugins ?

**VS2015**

[image]

**VS2019**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the Source Control option in **Team Project** :

[image]

Instead of the Source Control option in **Team Project Collection**

[image]